# APT pinning/apt -t myreleasehere: how do I tell apt to use the information provided in -t when installing dependencies?

Tags: apt

as title.

I am installing something from a 3rd party repo and apt wants to use the the dependency that's available in the default repo instead of the higher version dependency that's available in the 3rd party repo.

This is what I trying to install

```
apt -t 3rdparty install my-package-here
```

These are the contents of /etc/apt/preferences

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 1000

Package: *
Pin: release a=3rdparty
Pin-Priority: 500
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From `man apt_preferences`, the `Pin-Priority: 1000` has the intended behaviour:

```
P >= 1000
     causes a version to be installed even if this constitutes a downgrade of the package
```

So you rather should assign the priority `1000` to the `3rdparty` section than to the `stable` section. I think you also can delete the `stable` section as the default priority is `500` and normally is not added explicitly to the `apt` configuration.